# ALM 12.21: How to update Test Case after new parameters added to business component

Tags: alm

In ALM 12.21:

How can I update the parameters in a test case (type businesss process) after I added new parameters to a business component that is part of the test script?

I have found now way to update the test case for the new parameters in the business component.

So far, the only way to get the new parameters into the test is to delete the business component from test script an add it again.

Which is cumbersome as I am creating lots of Test Cases using this workflow:

1. Create Test
2. Create Business Component request when new BC for Test is needed
3. Writing Business Component steps, including parameters when needed
4. Writing Test Configuration to fill the needed parameters in 1 to n iterations

Right now, between steps 3 and 4, I have to delete an re-add the BC from Test Script so that the new parameters show.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you are using version control, you must check in the test before the test config change is seen. Naturally, you have to refresh the view, too